# Inserting merged column above existing columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a merged column with name "My Company" above columns "A" and "B".
How do I do it with python?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B": ["x", "y", "z"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with a dictionary and `axis=1`:

```
out = pd.concat({'My Company': df}, axis=1)
```

output:

```
  My Company   
           A  B
0          1  x
1          2  y
2          3  z
```

New columns index:

```
MultiIndex([('My Company', 'A'),
            ('My Company', 'B')],
           )
```